# How the Filter function is working?

Tags: angularjs

I have these few lines of code in an example. The Tutorial explains that filter function matches and returns matched country record. Where & how the entry.name was set.

```
myApp.controller('detailcontroller', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $scope.name=$routeParams.countryname;
  $http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {
     var country =data.filter(function(entry) {
        return entry.name === $scope.name;
     }) [0];


  console.log(country);
});

});
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: The `data.filter(...)` method is accepting an anonymous function which it will presumably call on each item in the `data` variable, in order to determine whether each item meets the conditions in the supplied function (i.e. the name of the item being equal to the `$scope.name` variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't "set". You specify an iterator (callback) function to the filter function.

The docs says : `Function to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.`

So basically, `entry` represents an element of the array. For each of the elements in the array, your function will be called with the element as parameter (if you have an array of countries, entry will be the first country, then the second one, etc.).

Maybe this is easier to understand for you :

```
var testIfCountryMatches = function(country){
    console.log("is "+country+" France ? : "+(country.name === "France"));
    return country.name === "France";
}

var matchingCountries = data.filter(testIfCountryMatches);
var fr = matchingCountries[0];
```